# excel conditional to php conditonal (if-else)

Tags: php, excel, if-statement

i have a excel conditional formul and i want it convert to php. I try but i receive wrong result.

thats excel code:

```
=IF(I3<=24000-G3;G3*0,15;IF(I3<24000;((24000-I3)*0,15+(G3-(24000-I3))*0,2);IF(I3<=53000-G3;G3*0,2;IF(I3<53000;(53000-I3)*0,2+(G3-(53000-I3))*0,27;IF(I3<=190000-G3;G3*0,27;IF(I3<190000;(190000-I3)*0,27+(G3-(190000-I3))*0,35;G3*0,35))))))
```

and my php code:

```
$gelirvergisi = 0;
$kumulatifgelirvergisi = 0;
if ($kumulatifgelirvergisi <= (24000 - $gelirvergisimatrah))
{
    $gelirvergisi = $gelirvergisimatrah * 0.15;

} else if ($kumulatifgelirvergisi < 24000)
{
    $gelirvergisi = ((24000 - $kumulatifgelirvergisi) * 0.15 + ($gelirvergisimatrah - (24000 - $kumulatifgelirvergisi)) * 0.2);

}  else if ($kumulatifgelirvergisi <= (53000 - $gelirvergisimatrah)) {
            $gelirvergisi = $gelirvergisimatrah * 0.2;

}
else if ($kumulatifgelirvergisi < 53000)
{
    $gelirvergisi = (53000 - $kumulatifgelirvergisi) * 0.2 + ($gelirvergisimatrah - (53000 - $kumulatifgelirvergisi)) * 0.27;

}
else if ($kumulatifgelirvergisi <= (190000 - $gelirvergisimatrah))
{
    $gelirvergisi = $gelirvergisimatrah * 0.27;

}
else if ($kumulatifgelirvergisi < 190000)
{
    $gelirvergisi = (190000 - $kumulatifgelirvergisi) * 0.27 + ($gelirvergisimatrah - (190000 - $kumulatifgelirvergisi)) * 0.35;
}
else
{
    $gelirvergisi = $gelirvergisimatrah * 0.35;
}
```

**i update php code

I3 : $kumulatifgelirvergisi
G3 : $gelirvergisimatrah

test url: https://profaj.co/guleryuz/hesaplamalar/netten-brute-ucret-hesaplamasi/

Comment: Just want to say that your first if is `I3<=24000` and second one is `I3<24000`. Is that right? Because your second IF is useless because in the first one you are already using `<`. Same happens every two ifs...

Comment: Is that excel even legal syntax?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns The first one is `I3<=24000-G3` (note the subtraction of `G3`) and same goes for every other if that follows, so the first condition doesn't necessarily exclude the second one.

Comment: excel formula working. its right. https://i.ibb.co/SRjxhd4/excelformula.png. my problem in php

Comment: @El_Vanja You are absolutely right!!! My bad